# R how to plot groups of data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with data like

```
year    range            count
2011    '0 to 500'       10
2011    '500 to 1000'    100
2012    '0 to 500'       12
2012    '500 to 1000'    50
2013    '0 to 500'       22
2013    '500 to 1000'    75
```

How can I use ggplot to plot Range on the x axis, count on the y axis and a line of each year?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a duplicate so I've provided an answer. You data structure require some minimal treatment of text (to extract to and from) and probably geom_segments instead of geom_line.

```
 s<-"year;range;count
 2011;'0 to 500';10
 2011;'500 to 1000';100
 2012;'0 to 500';12
 2012;'500 to 1000';50
 2013;'0 to 500';22
 2013;'500 to 1000';75"

 d<-read.delim(textConnection(s),header=TRUE,sep=";",strip.white=TRUE)
 d$range <- as.character(d$range) # remove factor
 d$range <- gsub("'","",d$range) # remove character
# strsplit returns a list, one per line, with two elements, here i'm getting
# each of those elements
d$from<-as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(d$range,' to '),function(X)X[1]))
d$to<-as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(d$range,' to '),function(X)X[2]))
d$year <- as.factor(d$year)
ggplot(d)+geom_segment(aes(x=from,xend=to,y=count,yend=count,col=year))
```

[image: segments]